# How to set up a one word alias for intranet site on windows server 2008 R2 running IIS

Tags: iis, webserver, iis-7.5, alias, windows-server-2008-r2

I would like users to be able to type in one word in their browser that will direct them to an intranet site, instead of having to put in the full url. I'm running IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2. I've researched and found some suggestions, like adding a site binding, as well as editing the hosts file to add the server IP address with an alias but nothing has worked yet. I do have a virual directory set up that shortens the url, but would like to use just a single word as an alias. How can I do this?

I've attached a screenshot here of my website configuration in IIS - the page I want to set up the short name for is under the highlighted directory Which is also a virtual directory):

[image]

Comment: Is your intranet site in an Active Directory network? Then the DNS suffix  is added to the network card of your client computers, so the domain is added to the URL in the background (e.g you type server and requests go to server.example.com). What error message do your users receive? Editing the hosts file on client computers should work as well, as should adding an extra binding to your IIS web site.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is in an active directory. With the help of IT at my agency I was able to get the short name to point to the server, but not to the specific site itself. I did add a binding as well. Perhaps it is an issue with my how website is set up: all of my web pages are in a subdirectory underneath the website. I've added a screenshot above with the folder highlighted the contains the web pages, including the one I want to set up the short name for (it's also a virtual directory). Maybe this should be setup differently?